# Running .sh file why does it pause with a : waiting for user input before continuing to run?

Tags: shell, terminal

[image]

When executing a .sh file that contains multiple commands, on multiple lines, it pauses, with a colon :.  At that point, it only continues if I press the spacebar and the letter q.  Is there any way to force it to continue running, without those pauses?

```
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion 
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id ?????????????? --dashboard-id ?????????????????? --grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:??????????????:user/default/firstName.LastName,Actions=quicksight:DescribeDashboard,quicksight:ListDashboardVersions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions,quicksight:QueryDashboard,quicksight:UpdateDashboard,quicksight:DeleteDashboard,quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions,quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion
```

Comment: What is the content of the script file? I think there is a call to the `read` command waiting for an input.

Comment: Hi @CarloCorradini,  The script file executes multiple AWS commands, but none of them call a read command.

Comment: Can you share the script? Without any information it's hard to understand what is the possible cause :/

Comment: Hi @CarloCorradini,

I've appended a redacted version of the script in the description above.  It's basically the same command, run 31 times, on different QuickSight dashboards.

Comment: It's not shell, it's `aws`. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122188/how-to-turn-off-the-pager-for-aws-cli-return-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346608/aws-cli-output-automatically-being-sent-to-vi#60356209

Comment: The `:` is printed by `less` (your pager) as started by aws; the shell has nothing to do with it.